# How to resolve Facebook Login is currently unavailable for this app, since we are updating additional details for this app

Tags: facebook-login

I am receiving the Facebook Message Dialog with the message:
Facebook Login is currently unavailable for this app, since we are updating additional details for this app

Answer (score 45):

In the facebook developers console for your app,  go to App Review-> Permissions and Features.   Set the public_profile and email to have advanced access.   This will allow all facebook users to have access and these two settings are auto granted.    Ensure the Access Level indicates Advanced Access

[image: facebook developer console showing advanced access]

Comment: Thanks for your info. Facebook Login of the iOS app is working well without the Advanced Access setting.

Comment: I Love you! That works :) !!!

Comment: Thanks Advance Access setting worked for me. :)

Comment: This works, thank you very very much, At first I thought I needed to upload photo of ID card to verify with Facebook.

Comment: Thanks man! You're really a man of culture, was stuck with this error for 4 hours.

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked after I told an admin to do Business Verification as stated in the second answer. He also added advanced access for public_profile,  which solved the issue.

Comment: first you need the Business Verification

Answer (score 11):

Note: As per Facebook new term you need to add **Business Verification** For Facebook login also.

Starting May 5,2023, all apps making new requests for Advanced Access, including for **email** and **public profile**, will require **Business Verification.**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference#login_permissions

Comment: Thank you! First and second answers resolved my issue.

Comment: This answer is correct, you need business verification, is your app still working Bhdr without business verification?

Comment: I had a working app that stopped working when Facebook required business verification @TMSAL.

Comment: Verified but still not working. How long does it take ?

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rX7jc.png)

first app mode live and then give advance permission in email and profileimage
tap again again for advance permission and  app mode live

Answer (score 0):

1. If you dont know already find the Email associated with your facebook account :
   facebook.com > Setting > Apps > GOG > (getEmail)
2. Using the email use Reset password in GOG login.
3. Follow the reset password instructions and log in using your email and new password.