# Feature Unavailable: facebook login is currently unavailable for this app since we are updating additional details for this app. Please Try again

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, facebook

I am working in React Native. I am trying to login with a Facebook account I get this error from Facebook
**I am receiving the Facebook Message Dialog with the message: Facebook Login is currently unavailable for this app, since we are updating additional details for this app**

Comment: any updates? has our solution helped?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**This arises due to the Pending Data use Checkup**

Please check in your developer account if you have a pending Data use Checkup. Once you complete it, it should work.

1.Enter https://developers.facebook.com/apps

2.You should see your app in red color with a note that Data Checkup is due.

3.You'll need to spend a few minutes to fill in a simple form...

Now you are Good to Go !!!

Comment: There's no Data Checkup on my app page. Any other possibilities?

Comment: I have checked it and there is nothing pending but also facebook login is not working...

Comment: Same problem - and no data checkup noted.

Answer (score 4):

As per Facebook new term you need to add **Business Verification** For Facebook login also.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76286958/6128573

Comment: I think this may be what just hit us - dumb that it does not follow the same bannering and inbox-messaging system as other threats to app being kept online.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have enabled App auth within the [Facebook development console](https://developers.facebook.com/apps), check that you have all the essential setup steps, and provided a current and valid privacy policy.

Once your health checks are in place, your app should be valid to authenticate with your firebase app.