# Facebook Login is current unavailable for this app in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

I am facing this error while doing Facebook authentication. Facebook Login is currently unavailable for this app.

Below error is shown:
Feature Unavailable: Facebook Login is currently unavailable for this app, since we are updating additional detail for this app, please try again later[image]

Comment: Please reply to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Check that below permission have advance access.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Note: As per Facebook new term you need to add **Business Verification** For Facebook login also.

Here is the all detail
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76286958/6128573

Answer (score 0):

With respect to the all the other answers, here's the screenshot to help someone.

---

1. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/

---

2. Click on the Apps menu on the top bar.

---

3. Select the respective app from the drop down.

[image]

The circle next to your app name is not fully green. When you hover mouse on it, you'll see a popup saying, "Not available to all users because your app is not live."

So next, you've to make it publicly available.

---

4. Click on setting at left panel. [see the screenshot below]

[image]

---

5. In Basic tab add your "Contact Email" (a valid email address - I've added the one which I'm using with developers.facebook.com) and make "Save changes".

---

6. Next click "App Review" at left panel. [see the screenshot below]

---

7. Look for this, **Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?** and Turn ON the switch next to this.

[image]

---

8. That's it! - App is now publicly available. See the fully green circle next to the app name.
   [image]

Comment: So do you mean the issue is due to not making the app live?