# How to resolve "Facebook Login is currently unavailable for this app, since we are updating additional details for this app"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

My app facebook login feature was suspended with error: "Facebook Login is currently unavailable for this app, since we are updating additional details for this app" 2 days ago.

So, I have performed the following action today:

1. Business Verification (Both Business Account & Developer Account now shows "Verified")
2. public_profile & email in Developer Account are at "Advanced Access" with "Advanced Access granted"

Unfortunately, the error still persist on my app. So, any things I can do in order to make the feature resume normal immediately or how long would it take for facebook login feature resume normal?

I have also read through this: [How to resolve Facebook Login is currently unavailable for this app, since we are updating additional details for this app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68567360/how-to-resolve-facebook-login-is-currently-unavailable-for-this-app-since-we-ar). The steps are same as what I have done, still no luck.

Comment: To supplement, I can facebook login on my app only if i use a facebook account that can access both business and developer account. Other personal / user facebook account fail to social login and result in the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by waiting for 24 hours with the above actions